# Isolating page-refresh: Can I embed a sub-page as a content element in TYPO3 10.4.9?

Tags: typo3

Here's the problem:
Our TYPO3-based site has a video and a form with questions below. When you submit the form, the whole page reloads, which is a problem because of the video.

Perhaps it is possible to have the form on a sub-page, which is then embedded as a content element on the main page? Would this solve our problem and if so, can it be implemented with TYPO3?

Comment: Adding a form as a content element has nothing to do here. If you want to send forms without page refreshing you need to find or create custom extension, which sends it via AJAX. Everything can be implemented in TYPO3 that just framework for coding your requirements based on CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are using for adding a form but if you you are using powermail you could add this to your TypoScript Setup:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.ajaxSubmit = 1
```

Found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/stable/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/AjaxSubmit/Index.html